# What is the best way to safely display uploaded files in browser with PHP 5.2

Tags: php, file, upload, mime-types, php-5.2

I am trying to serve files uploaded by users with PHP.

While it would be easy to just point to the file, there seems to be agreement that you should not point directly to a directory on the site as this creates a security risk...If someone can get a malicious file past barriers onto site, it is then a cinch for them to execute it if they know where it sits on server.  Instead, recommendation is to put files in a folder outside the tree structure of the site, store name in database as something other than original name, along with a file path to the hidden directory, and serve it using a PHP file that reads and displays.  I am able to do all this and display gibberish using:

```
// get mime type somehow//

header("Content-type:".$mimetype);
readfile($totalfilepath);
```

The problem is how to get the correct mime type so it displays a nice file instead of gibberish.

If you have 5.3, you can use finfo as follows:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
header("Content-Type: ".finfo_file($finfo, 'files/'.$file));
finfo_close($finfo);
readfile('files/'.$file);
```

Unfortunately, finfo doesn't work in 5.2  There is also a function called

```
mime_content_type
```

however, it is deprecated as of 4.xx and is not on my server in any case. From what I have read, there does not seem to be a reliable way to get the mime type before 5.3.  I don't want to upgrade to 5.3 as it will require upgrading of a very large site.

Note: the files that are allowed for upload include .jpg, .gif, .png, .pdf files, the major office files, doc, docs, xls, xlx, etc. and txt files.

Also, I would be open to forcing a download of the files instead of displaying them in browser, however, first choice is displaying in browser.

Comment: This was a really well researched thought out question in contrast to thousands of lame questions on this site that don't get downvoted.  Why would you downvote it?  My specific question is how do you get mime-type in 5.2? or if that is impossible is there an alternative way to serve uploaded files.  Simple enough for you?

Comment: Are you OK with the user DOWNLOADING the file? Or does it have to be displayed on the screen? Not all files can be displayed...

Comment: Prior to the 5.3 finfo functions, the PECL [fileinfo extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/Fileinfo) was used.

Comment: I would be okay with downloading.  The file types are limited to those mentioned above, but if there is no reliable way to display, downloading is definitely okay.

Comment: The site is hosted by a 3rd party.  I don't think they have the PECL package installed.

Comment: @nute: there's no difference between "viewing" and "downloading". Either way, the file is downloaded server->client. what happens to it after that is entirely up to the client-side browser.

Comment: I was going to suggest ignoring the MIME type altogether or using a default one (octet-stream), and using just the "attachment" idea.

Comment: If you have a large application, as you say, but are obviously running it on a host which is not under your control, then I think the problem is not with the application but the server environment. As mentioned here, 5.2 is out of support but if you stick with it, the PECL package is a good solution. If you're able to install such packages, you're on the wrong host IMO.

Comment: For the time being I am going to use 'application/force-download' as at least this lets the user download the file.  Using file extension doesn't seem like such a great idea not only for security reason as it can be spoofed but also because there seem to be multiple mime types for things like pdf files and it might cause errors. And using magic string from something like PECL won't work until we switch providers or upgrade to 5.3 and use fileinfo.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hakre was able to get a few shills to close question, but not before I got enough information to answer question and solve my problem.    Good programmers answer, bad ones kvetch.  Here's to good programmers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The required information is returned by the `getimagesize()` function. How to get this information is explained in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). The `image_type_to_mime_type()` function can be helpful, too. [Examples](http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php) are provided in the online manual too.

Comment: Do you know if this works for non image files such as pdf, doc, xls, ppt etc. ?? I have used it for image files, but my recollection and documention in manual suggests it only works for image files.

Comment: To my knowledge it does not -- it works for image files.  If you want to validate the contents of the other files, you may have to write additional code